# Moxy падает при инициализации фрагмента MvpAppCompatFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, moxy

Пытаюсь освоить Moxy 2.1.2

Падает с при ошибкой:

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #0 bootstrap method
    at moxy.MvpDelegate.<clinit>(MvpDelegate.java:37)
    at moxy.MvpAppCompatFragment.getMvpDelegate(MvpAppCompatFragment.java:108)
    at ru.example.stat.fragments.EventFragment.<init>(EventFragment.kt:36)
    at ru.example.stat.actyvities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:58)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Я так понял беда во фрагменте

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import moxy.MvpAppCompatFragment
import moxy.ktx.moxyPresenter
import ru.example.stat.R
import ru.example.stat.presenters.EventPresenter
import ru.example.stat.views.EventView


class EventFragment : MvpAppCompatFragment(R.layout.fragment_events), EventView{

    private val eventPresenter by moxyPresenter { EventPresenter() }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events, container, false)
}
```

Что не так делаю, в чем может быть проблема?

В MainActivity onCreate:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)


    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)
    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    val fragment = EventFragment()
    addFragment(fragment)
}

private fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.javaClass.getSimpleName())
        .commit()
}
```

gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.example.stat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    //MOXY

    def moxyVersion = "2.1.2"
    implementation "com.github.moxy-community:moxy:$moxyVersion"
    kapt "com.github.moxy-community:moxy-compiler:$moxyVersion"
    implementation "com.github.moxy-community:moxy-android:$moxyVersion"
    implementation "com.github.moxy-community:moxy-androidx:$moxyVersion"
    implementation "com.github.moxy-community:moxy-material:$moxyVersion"
    implementation "com.github.moxy-community:moxy-ktx:$moxyVersion"

    //GraphView
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5'

    def room_version = "2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    //Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.4"
}
```

Comment: а можете еще полный код __build.gradle__ в вопрос добавить, пожалуйста?)

Comment: добавил build.gradle

Comment: Ну что, у Вас получилось?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в gradle файл

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Прямо над

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: Помогло спасибо. Ну там же написано что это для java, а для kotlin kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

Comment: В случае Kotlin _kotlinOptions_ нужен дополнительно, помимо того, что нужно для Java